# Group Pivot results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot, pivot-table

After a longtime of googling and figuring out how to put my data in a decent pivot table with dynamic row headers I got to this point.

The only thing I can't figure out is how to group the results by [Location] and how to replace NULL by 'zero' / 0?

To replace NULL by 0 I tried ISNULL() and COALESCE() in this line, but it doesnt change the NULL:

```
    SELECT COALESCE(ROUND(CAST([Remaining Quantity] AS decimal (2,0)), 1),0) AS [Remaining QuantityRound], *
```

or

```
    SELECT ISNULL(ROUND(CAST([Remaining Quantity] AS decimal (2,0)), 1),0) AS [Remaining QuantityRound], *
```

The SQL query I have now:

```
    DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    declare @item varchar(max);
    declare @open varchar(max);

    set @item = 291557
    set @open = 1

    --Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
    SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
           + QUOTENAME([Size])
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [Size] FROM [Table] WHERE [Item] = @item AND [Open] = @open) AS Items

    --Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
    SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
      'SELECT [Location], ' + @ColumnName + '
        FROM 
        (SELECT ROUND(CAST([Quantity] AS decimal (2,0)), 1) AS [QuantityRound], * FROM [Table]  
        WHERE [Item] = ''' + @item + ''' AND [Open] = ''' + @open + ''') x
        PIVOT(SUM([QuantityRound])
              FOR [Size] IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'
    --Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query

    EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

Result:

```
    Location   S      M        L
    001        1      NULL     NULL
    001        NULL   1        NULL
    002        NULL   NULL     2
    002        NULL   1        NULL
```

What I would like to achieve:

```
    Location   S      M        L
    001        1      1        0
    002        0      1        2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `*` in the subquery:

```
(SELECT ROUND(CAST([Quantity] AS decimal (2,0)), 1) AS [QuantityRound], SIZE, LOCATION FROM [Table]
```

The extra columns are causing the extra rows.

Comment: He also needs to convert `NULL` values to 0. Will have to write a separate expression in the select column list.

Comment: If I remove the * in the subquery, I get the error:

    Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
    Invalid column name 'Size'.
    Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
    Invalid column name 'Location'.

Comment: Are you including `size` and `location`?

Comment: Thats it, thanks!
Can I also order the table by `Location`?
I tried with `ORDER BY [Location]` at the end of the `PIVOT` but I don't see any changes

Comment: @Bldjef . . . I think you can use `order by` in a `pivot` query, but that is a different question.